# Call field from zip() into Field Calculator expression ArcGIS

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, field-calculator, error-000539

I've been trying to find a way to call in field names from a zip(). Basically I have 12 fields called "Flw_days1", "Flw_days2" etc and corresponding "Depth" fields that need to be calculated using the inputs of the "Flw_days" fields. I.e. "Depth1" is calculated using "Flw_Days1" and so on.

I've used the zip() function to match these together and then tried to call these into a codeblock and expression for use in the field calculator.

See example below:

```
depth_fields = ["Depth1", "Depth2", "Depth3", "Depth4", "Depth5", "Depth6", "Depth7", "Depth8", "Depth9", "Depth10", "Depth11", "Depth12"]
flow_fields = ["!Flw_Day1!", "!Flw_Day2!", "!Flw_Day3!", "!Flw_Day4!", "!Flw_Day5!", "!Flw_Day6!", "!Flw_Day7!", "!Flw_Day8!", "!Flw_Day9!", "!Flw_Day10!", "!Flw_Day11!", "!Flw_Day12!"]

zipped = zip(sorted(depth_fields), sorted(flow_fields))

for input in zipped:
  codeblock = """
def depth(flow, kfc, rf):
  if kfc == 0 or rf == 0:
    return ""
  else:
    return (flow * (kfc / rf) + 2)
"""
  expression = "depth(input[0], !K_FC!, !Ret_Fact!)"
  arcpy.CalculateField_management(CMPP_fc, input[1], expression, "PYTHON_9.3", codeblock)
```

As you can see I have tried to call the "Flw_Days" field into the expression and the "Depth" field into the field calculator.

The error I get is:

```
Runtime error <class 'arcgisscripting.ExecuteError'>: ERROR 000539: Error running expression: depth(input[0], 0, 0) <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

So it seems to be calling the input[0] into the expression that is causing the issue.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.

Comment: Maybe use an UpdateCursor instead of trying to call Field Calculator -- this would let you iterate through the rows one at a time, avoiding the need for the codeblock.

Comment: Instead of using field calculator to do something this complicated, it would be a lot simpler to use cursors.

Comment: Also, side note (still think UpdateCursor would be more straightforward) -- do you need exclamation points around the depth_fields, e.g. `"!Depth1!"`?

Comment: And finally: in the above code, `zip(sorted(flow_fields), sorted(depth_fields))` -- depth_fields should be first, flow_fields should be second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an UpdateCursor lets you avoid the codeblock and directly work with the row data, instead of dealing with the Field Calculator. For example, in 10.1:

```
depth_fields = # list of depth fields
flow_fields = # list of flow fields

zipped = zip(sorted(depth_fields), sorted(flow_fields))

for input in zipped:
    fields = (input[0], input[1], 'K_FC', 'Ret_Fact')
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(CMPP_fc, fields) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if row[2] == 0 or row[3] == 0:
                # error message?
            else:
                row[0] = row[1] * (row[2] / row[3]) + 2
                cursor.updateRow(row)
```

For 10.0, which doesn't have DA cursors, you can use a regular Update Cursor. The basic idea is the same, but it needs to call the fields specifically since it's not limiting its initial query:

```
depth_fields = # list of depth fields
flow_fields = # list of flow fields

zipped = zip(sorted(depth_fields), sorted(flow_fields))

for input in zipped:
    fields = (input[0], input[1], 'K_FC', 'Ret_Fact')
    cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(CMPP_fc)
    for row in cursor:
        flow = row.getValue(fields[1])
        kfc = row.getValue(fields[2])
        rf = row.getValue(fields[3])
        # pulled values from rows into variables to simplify following code; not required
        if kfc == 0 or rf == 0:
            row.setValue(fields[0],'')
        else:
            depth = flow * (kfc / rf) + 2
            row.setValue(fields[0], depth)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
    del row, cursor
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. The code above doesn't loop through the 12 Flw_Day and Depth fields. Even so I tried it to see if it worked with just the single fields and I got the error "Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: Object: Error in parsing arguments for UpdateCursor". It's worth noting that I am working in ArcGIS 10 and therefore had to modify the code so that it used arcpy.UpdateCursor rather than arcpy.da.UpdateCursor, could this be causing the issue?

Comment: I've updated the script so it can fully loop through; I wasn't sure how much help you'd need replacing the Field Calculator part, but erred on the side of less and gave an example rather than a working script. Hope the new version helps.

Comment: Ah I almost got to the same script myself today but kept getting a few different errors. Your updated code works perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be accomplished with one update cursor, I find it easier to separate the two. Here's the somewhat tested code to get you started with cursors. I created a mock feature class with 26 fields filled with random values and I picked two of them to compare with field calculator and it seemed to be correct. Feel free to ask for clarification.

```
import arcpy
#Create two lists of input and output fields.    
flow_fields, depth_fields = zip(*(("Flw_Day{}".format(i),
                                "Depth{}".format(i)) for i in xrange(1,13)))

#Create list of lists containing each record's attributes for each field.
flow_data = [[r for r in row] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CMPP_fc, flow_fields)]

other_data = [[r for r in row] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(CMPP_fc, ['K_FC', 'Ret_Fact'])]

#Bulk update each field
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(CMPP_fc, depth_fields) as rows:
    #The first counter loops over each feature
    for j,row in enumerate(rows):
        #The second counter loops over each field for every feature
        for k,_ in enumerate(depth_fields):
            if other_data[j][0] == 0 or other_data[j][1] == 0:
                row[k] = ""
            else:
                row[k] = flow_data[j][k] * other_data[j][0] / other_data[j][1] + 2
            rows.updateRow(row)
```

There's definitely a more efficient method, since you're checking `K_FC` and `Ret_Fact` for each field instead of once per feature. But unless you're running this code often or on massive datasets, it should work well enough. It might work to bring the `if` statement before the second `for` loop....

Comment: I perhaps should have said that I am working with ArcGIS 10 which as far as I am aware doesn't have the arcpy.da.UpdateCursor function? I tried modifying your code with the arcpy.UpdateCursor but got the error message - "Runtime error <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: Object: Error in parsing arguments for UpdateCursor". Sorry for not specifying this and thank you for your help.